# Trying to understand how the PATH is set on linux (bash on Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, bash, path

---

EDIT

The answer to my question is actually obvious, I simply forgot about the meaning of the EXPORT keyword. I still drop the explanation here, just in case.

So in a few words, when opening a terminal with Ctrl-Alt T a new shell is created, which is a child of the shell created at loggin. As explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), the loggin shell is initialized by reading */etc/profile*, and as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html) and more specifically [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) elements of the environment are transmitted to child processes, notably variables prefixed with the EXPORT keyword.

---

I am trying to understand what is the mechanism under which the `PATH` is set under linux when opening a new (virtual) terminal.

I know one can change the `PATH` in several files (e.g. system : */etc/{profile*, *bash.bashrc*, ... } or user: *~/{.profile*, *.bash_login*, *.bashrc*... }, some of which are read at login, the others when opening new (virtual) terminals.

According to my tests, it seems the "*profile*" files are read at startup (when the user logs in), which registers some startup values for variables such as `PATH`. Then, each time a terminal is opened these startup values are provided to other script (e.g. *bashrc*) for further configuration, resulting in something like : `PATH_IN_TERMINAL=$BASHRC_ADDONS:$PATH_FROM_PROFILE`

Notably, *~/.profile* won't normally be read after login. Changing this file won't have any effect in the current session and the `PATH_FROM_PROFILE` part of the `PATH` will remain the same until one logs in again (after logout or through ssh connection for instance).

Am I correct ? And if so, where can I find a doc on the subject ?

Thanks

Comment: This is entirely a configuration question which you've already answered for yourself. Ultimately, `PATH` is just a value (possibly inherited from the parent process) that can be modified at will; doing so by sourcing existing configuration files is just one way, and every machine could have a different set up.

Comment: Also, it's perfectly normal for `~/.profile` to be read after login; it's just as normal for `bash` to ignore it in favor of `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile` if either is present.

Comment: You perfectly summarized my question with your sentence "(possibly inherited from the parent process)".
As Mentioned in my question, I know about the standard configuration files as well as the conditions and order in which they are read. 
But I couldn't find anything concerning the transmission of environment variables from a login shell to children terminals (or shells for that matter.).

Comment: Oups... Actually, my question was indeed stupid.
Thanks to your keyword "inherited" I managed to dig up relevant pages in google, which simply reminded me the semantics of the "EXPORT" keyword :s

Answer (score 0):

This is the best explanation I have found on the subject: [Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

The simple explanation, in most common situations is:

1. Upon initial login to host, read `/etc/profile` followed by the first of
   `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`. `~/.profile` is
   supported by multiple shells, so is preferred.
2. When Bash starts, but not immediately after login, read `~/.bashrc`.

So, `profile` files are intended to run upon login and should be used to print initial messages (e.g. Security Warning, Message of the Day), check mail, and configure settings/variables that rarely change. Either system-wide (quotas, MOTD, etc.), or user-specific (timezone, locale, terminal, etc.).

`.bashrc` files are intended for individual users to customize their interactive experience. e.g. defining aliases, setting prompts, adding to PATH, etc.

I almost always add `source ~/.bashrc` to the end of my `.profile` file so that my shell is always customized to my requirements, even immediately after login.

NOTE: The above only applies to interactive shells (e.g. running on a terminal). None of these files are read if bash is run non-interactively (e.g. via `cron`). In those cases, you should create a different file containing required variables and specify that via the `BASH_ENV` environment file.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I did read the same info in the bash manpages but couldn't guess what was the difference between interactive and non interactive. Thanks for making that clear for me.
That being said, I finally realized the answer to my question is in the EXPORT keyword.